# iPhone battery capacity values in mAH

Tags: iphone, battery, iokit, uidevice

I would like to know how to have the data capacity in Mha for iPhone/iPad battery.
I would put them in an application that I intend to put on appstore and then I can not use IOKit.
Does anyone know how I can get these values?

Comment: You mean Milli-Amp-Hours (mAH)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
batteryLevel

The battery charge level for the device.
@property (nonatomic, readonly) float batteryLevel
Discussion

Battery level ranges from 0.0 (fully discharged) to 1.0 (100% charged). Before accessing this property, ensure that battery monitoring is enabled.

If battery monitoring is not enabled, battery state is UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown and the value of this property is –1.0.
Availability

    Available in iOS 3.0 and later.

See Also

      @property batteryState
      @property batteryMonitoringEnabled

Declared In
UIDevice.h
```

From [UIDevice Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/batteryLevel)

An then you can add to your app an plist where you will put all battery capacity for every device, read device model and with the percentange of battery and full capacity you can get the actual value in mAH.